# Tornado: how to dispatch different requests to a same class

Tags: tornado

I'm using Tornado to build a web server. I need to dispatch different requests into a same class. Here is an example:

```
application.add_handlers(r"^(example).*", [
(r"/(mark)/(auth)"), MarkHandler,
(r"/(mark)"), MarkHandler,
])
```

And the class `MarkHandler`:

```
class MarkHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, mark):   # /(mark)
        print('1111')

    def get(self, mark, auth):    # /(mark)/(auth)
        print('2222')
```

However, it doesn't seem to work...
When I visit the link: `www.example.com/mark`, the server gives me an error:

> TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'auth'

What I need as above is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't allow method overloading the way C++ or Java does. Defining the same method `get` twice in Python simply overwrites the first method with the second one.

Instead, you want a default value for the second argument:

```
class MarkHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, mark, auth=None):
        if auth is not None:
            print('2222')
        else:
            print('1111')
```